# Angular's mat-expansion-panel showing content when collapsed

Tags: angular

[image: Picture]

As you can see the TestGroup1 panel is showing that it is collapsed (based on the arrow) but yet I can still see the content of the panel. When I click it, it opens and closes normally (like TestGroup2).

I do have this in my expansion panel `[expanded]="panelOpenState"`
Which is based on this that is set to a button above. Initially, it's set to false.

```
togglePanel() {
this.panelOpenState = !this.panelOpenState;
}
```

Html code

```
      <div class="component-panel-body">
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let group of groups[selectedDeviceSource.id]" [expanded]="panelOpenState">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title> {{ group.name }} </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="qkFix">{{'TEAMVIEWER.DEVICE-ID' | translate}}</th>
            <th class="qkFix">{{'TEAMVIEWER.ALIAS' | translate}}</th>
            <th class="qkFix">{{'TEAMVIEWER.STATUS' | translate}}</th>
            <th class="qkFix">{{'TEAMVIEWER.OPTIONS' | translate}}</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr class="user-item" *ngFor="let device of group.devices" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
            <td class="qkFix">{{ device.deviceId }}</td>
            <td class="qkFix">{{ device.alias }}</td>
            <td class="qkFix" *ngIf="device.onlineState == 'Online'" ngClass="colorOnline">{{ device.onlineState }}
              <span class="dotOnline"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="qkFix" *ngIf="device.onlineState == 'Offline'" ngClass="colorOffline">{{ device.onlineState }}
              <span class="dotOffline"></span>
            </td>
            <td class="qkFix">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); showDevice(device); editDeviceDialog()">
                <i class="material-icons">{{ (auth.hasPermissions(['update-devices'], true)) ? 'edit' : 'open_in_new'}}</i>
              </button>
              <button [disabled]="!(auth.hasPermissions(['delete-devices'], true))" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();deleteDevice(device)">
                <i *ngIf="(auth.hasPermissions(['delete-devices'], true))" class="material-icons" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();deleteDevice(device)">delete</i>
                <i *ngIf="!(auth.hasPermissions(['delete-devices'], true))" class="material-icons" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">delete</i>
              </button>
              <button *ngIf="device.onlineState == 'Online'" [disabled]="!(auth.hasPermissions(['remote-control'], true))" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); remoteSession(device)">
                <i *ngIf="(auth.hasPermissions(['remote-control'], true))" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();remoteSession(device)" class="material-icons">swap_horiz</i>
                <i *ngIf="!(auth.hasPermissions(['remote-control'], true))" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="material-icons">swap_horiz</i>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please show us the template for this panel? it seems like, accordint to the rendering, you are showing data in the header rather than the body of the panel.

Comment: could you post the html part of the expansion-panel

Comment: @Supamiu and Izzo Obella, Oops forgot that, I've edited it now.

Comment: @Supamiu Yes, I'm also showing data in the header as well as the body.

Comment: How did you initialise panelOpenState?

Comment: @Vega  `public panelOpenState: boolean = false;` Just above the constructor.

Comment: Isn't mat-accordion helpful here? :)

Comment: @Vega I need to be able to open multiple panels at once, is that possible with mat-accordion?

Comment: I think so with multi=true? https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview#accordion

Comment: Here is a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t64uct

Comment: @Vega, Nope, but I did some research and apparently, this is fixed in the new Angular version. [Here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5269#issuecomment-365343567). Thanks for your help though!